# Is there way to remove cloud resources ONLY using AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

```
amplify delete
```

deletes both

1. the provisioned cloud resources and
2. the local \amplify folder, including any development and work you might have done on graphql schema, lambdas etc.

Is there a way to only deprovision the could resources in bulk from the command line that would cleanly preserve the local files. One way is to remove cloud resources one-by-one, but that's suboptimal and record of them being provisioned removes locally. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`amplify delete` is all-or-nothing deletion right now as far as I can tell. You can delete the Amplify app in the console manually though so it's no longer in the cloud and you still have your local files.

Keep in mind your local files will still reference the app you deleted so you'd probably need to create a new amplify project later on and then copy/paste the files you kept locally.

Comment: Thanks, the delete removes them and it doesn't look like this is currently possible. All articles seem to refer to keeping your schemas, mutations and other files copied/checked in outside of the local folder with is both their "home", but also dynamic in nature.